# ZeroDivisionError in Python

Tags: python

i just wondering, i build the code to ignore the zero division like this, since im new in python here's my code

```
product_a_sales = 5
product_b_sales = 5
total_sales = product_b_sales - product_a_sales
try:
product_a_percentage_sales = (product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
except ZeroDivisionError:
    product_a_percentage_sales=0
```

but eventually, it return an error :

```
File "<ipython-input-21-126bc16d81e9>", line 5
    product_a_percentage_sales = (product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
                             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

and im stuck with this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndentationError` is just as it says: an error in the indentation of your code. The line given must be indented.  Python uses indentation to tell when blocks of code start and end.  You should have something like

```
product_a_sales = 5
product_b_sales = 5
total_sales = product_b_sales - product_a_sales
try:
    product_a_percentage_sales = (product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
except ZeroDivisionError:
    product_a_percentage_sales=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a 4 spaces before this line

```
 product_a_percentage_sales = (product_a_sales/total_sales) * 100
```

Comment: Don't use single-space indentation. Use 4 spaces, [as PEP 8 recommends](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) and is standard. Or use a different number if your style guide recommends it, but I'm not aware of any that recommend 1.

Comment: i want to mean spaces no one space